# Exactly one solution to $ x\cdot a +y\cdot b = c $ with given $a,b \in \mathbb{N}\; c \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, euclidean-algorithm, gcd-and-lcm

how do I show that

> $ x\cdot a  +y\cdot b = c $
>
> with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c \in \mathbb{Z}$

has exactly one solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

(There are 2 numbers $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $ua+vb = c$)

if

> $gcd(a,b)\mid c$

I have no idea how to start the proof.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\,(x,y)\,$ is a solution then so too is $\,(x,y)+n(b,-a).\,$  So you need further constraints to force unqiueness. One way to proceed is to use the Bezout identity for the gcd. Do you know that?

Comment: I tried to add the missing parts. I have to admit that I haven't heard of the Bezout identity.